# Changing the name of an excel chart series with openpyxl, with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, series

So, I'm making some line charts with Openpyxl and to make them I changed the key strings of the dict (that is going as input for the workbook) to not be equal and always be a different string, so the data doesn't overwrite because some key string was equal. 
The problem is in the chart series name, I need them to be unchanged and not the title from the data column but the unchanged string that I have stored on other list.>br>

Is it possible to just change the name of the series in the chart and leave the column name not changed? (if the column name changed for the name i want the series name to be it was going to exist more than one column with the same name.)

This is the code I have:

```
x_values = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=sheet.max_row)
y_values = Reference(sheet, min_col=column_init, min_row=row_num, max_col=column_end, max_row=sheet.max_row)

Create the chart
chart = LineChart()

chart.style = 12

chart.add_data(y_values, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(y_values)
chart.set_categories(x_values)
chart.x_axis.number_format = 'hh:mm'  # 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'
chart.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "hours"
chart.x_axis.title = "Date"

graph_location = E2

sheet.add_chart(chart, graph_location)

book.save(excel_name)
```

I tried to change the series title, but that's not right and throws errors about the object type.

```
chart.series.title = "SeriesName-bup"
```

Comment: The code looks incomplete and broken: `data` is not defined, for example. Please include the full traceback of any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `titles_from_data=True`, create series for your data and set the title as you require

```
y_values = Reference(sheet, min_col=column_init, min_row=row_num, max_col=column_end, max_row=sheet.max_row)
series1 = Series(y_values, title='Whatever')
...

chart.append(series1)
```

Need to import 'Series' from 'openpyxl.chart' as well.

**Working Example**; 
The following example is a self contained example that incorporates your code as able and uses dummy data.

**Ensure that you are using the latest Openpyxl release, 3.1.2**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import Reference, LineChart, Series  # <-- Import Series


book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

### Test Data
rows = [
    ('Time', 'Values1', 'Values2'),
    ('01:00', 100, 200),
    ('02:00', 200, 300),
    ('03:00', 300, 400),
    ('04:00', 50, 20),
    ('05:00', 500, 600),
    ('06:00', 100, 200),
]

### Write test data to Sheet
for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)

#initialize LineChart object
chart = LineChart()

### X Axis names
x_values = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_col=1, max_row=7)

### Create Series1
data1 = Reference(sheet, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=7)
series1 = Series(data1, title='SeriesName-bup')
### Add Series1 to the chart
chart.append(series1)

### Create Series2
data2 = Reference(sheet, min_col=3, min_row=1, max_col=3, max_row=7)
series2 = Series(data2, title='ThisIsSeries2')
### Add Series2 to the chart
chart.append(series2)

### Set Chart Style
chart.style = 12

### Set X-axis
chart.set_categories(x_values)

##cosmetics
chart.title = 'Example'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Y Axis'
chart.x_axis.number_format = 'hh:mm'  # 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss'
chart.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "hours"
chart.x_axis.title = "Date"

### Add Chart to Sheet
graph_location = 'E2'
sheet.add_chart(chart, graph_location)

### Save workbook
book.save('line_chart.xlsx')
```

[image: Example Line Chart]

Comment: I tried this, but on the series1 line it gives Unexpected argument to title='Whatever'

And the possible import I found is "from openpyxl.chart.series import Series"

The following error is thrown:
TypeError: Series.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Comment: Included a working example

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I know the origin of the problem. I can't import Series from openpyxl.chart and i have the 3.1.2 release of Openpyxl installed..

Comment: Try removing and re-installing Openpyxl, this has been an import for dome time.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have that import without errors!